# Stripping start/end characters on regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
>>> re.findall(r'\r\n\d+\r\n',contents)[-1]
'\r\n1621\r\n'
>>> re.findall(r'\r\n\d+\r\n',contents)[-1].replace('\r','').replace('\n','')
'1621'
```

How would I improve the regular expression such that I don't need to use the python `replace` methods?

Note that the digit must be surrounded by those characters, I can't do a straight `\d+`.

Comment: You want a non-capturing group: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group

Comment: Do you care about not being able to match an adjacent digit's surrounded by \r\n ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use parenthesis:

```
re.findall(r'\r\n(\d+)\r\n',contents)[-1]
```

That way you match the given pattern and only get the parenthesis content in `findall` result.

Answer (score 0):

[user 5061](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4230591/user-5061) answer is great.
You can use `.strip()` to get rid of those `"\r\n"` special characters.

```
re.findall(r'\r\n\d+\r\n',contents)[-1].strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use look-ahead and look-back assertions:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=\r\n)\d+(?=\r\n)',contents)[-1]
```